# FileProvider attempting to invoke XmlResourceParser on a null String with External-path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

What i'm trying to do is open a file from:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.extension
```

When the Uri is to be created i get the exception

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser 
android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.Ged" android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:label="GED" android:icon="@drawable/iconTest"></application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <!--<application android:label="GEDNovo.Android">-->
  <application>
    <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content"
            android:authorities="com.Ged.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
  </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

So i created inside `xml` folder in `Res` a `provider_paths.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="/Download"/>
</paths>
```

OBS: I've already tried using `name=external_files` and `path="."` without success

Then here is my method using FileProvider:

```
public void OpenFileByName(string fileName, string path)
        {
            try
            {
                //var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                //var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);
                var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

                //Copy the private file's data to the EXTERNAL PUBLIC location

               // var externalPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/Download/" + fileName;

                Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
                file.SetReadable(true);

                string application = "";
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);

                // get application type
                switch (extension.ToLower())
                {
                    case ".txt":
                        application = "text/plain";
                        break;
                    case ".doc":
                    case ".docx":
                        application = "application/msword";
                        break;
                    case ".pdf":
                        application = "application/pdf";
                        break;
                    case ".xls":
                    case ".xlsx":
                        application = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                        break;
                    case ".jpg":
                    case ".jpeg":
                    case ".png":
                        application = "image/jpeg";
                        break;
                    default:
                        application = "*/*";
                        break;
                }
                Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                var filePackage = context.PackageName + ".fileprovider";
                var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, filePackage, file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                intent.SetDataAndType(uri, application);
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);


                Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

In this case the `string path` is  `/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.extension`

I've made a lot of research and none of the answers helped me. I tried to change `android:authorities="com.Ged.fileprovider"` to `android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"` and didn't work.

I'm without ideas.

Answer (score 0):

first change in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider
       android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
       android:authorities="com.Ged.fileprovider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

then in your `provider_paths.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

in your code (here is a sample for JPG which path is :`/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.jpg` ):

```
 if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)
     {
       var path =  Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
       string strpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "test.jpg");
       Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(strpath);
       var filePackage = PackageName + ".fileprovider";
       var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, filePackage, file);
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(PhotoActivity));
       intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
       intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
       StartActivity(intent);
     }
  else
     {

       RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 1);
     }
```

on Android 6.0 and above,you should request [Runtime Permission](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/),you could refer to this to modify your code

Comment: Tks for the answer. I tried it but didn't work, i stil get the same error as exception.
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: @MateusJ.S check `var filePackage = context.PackageName + ".fileprovider";` is the same as the `android:authorities="com.Ged.fileprovider"` which in your AndroidManifest

Comment: @MateusJ.S and you could try to define it directly `var filePackage = "com.Ged.fileprovider";`

Comment: for the first question YES, is exactly the same name. About the second one, i've already did that and the problem continues.